# How to become non-root in the middle of a shell script run as root? Possible?

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a shell script that runs a bunch of other sub-scripts.  I decide that my script must be run as root because the first several sub-scripts that it runs need to be run as root.  However, there are two sub-scripts run by the super-script that cannot be run as root.  Assuming my script was run as root, how do I de-root it for the last two sub-scripts?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need a specific non-root user that your sub-scripts can run under.  Let us call that user `fred`.  Then your script with root privileges can simply do

```
su fred /path/to/subscript-A
su fred /path/to/subscript-B
```

Contra nsayer's answer, you probably can NOT use `nobody` for this, because the entire point of `nobody` is that it has write privileges on *nothing*.  Sometimes that's exactly what you want, but I'm betting your sub-scripts need to write to the file system...

Comment: The point Zack is getting at is that the user must be a 'human' user with a shell to do anything useful, so for example `nobody` or `www-data` won't work. It's a good point, but it's not necessary to `su fred (some command)` every time... just `su fred`, then issue any commands as fred in separate commands, then `exit`.

Comment: @no: That only works if you have an interactive shell; from within a script, you have to give `su fred` a command.  You can of course wrap up a bunch of commands in a sub-script and pass that to `su`, but it sounds like the OP has already done that.  Also, fyi, `su -s /bin/sh fred -- -c exec /path/to/subscript` will work even if `fred` has no shell in `/etc/passwd`, and you may prefer to have `fred` that way if that account is only ever used from the script (which is probably a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

use `su` to run a command you want to run as some other user.

```
su nobody ls /tmp
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily wrong, but the odds are that the sub-script needs to write the file system, at which point (AIUI) one must not use `nobody`.

Comment: He wasn't nearly that specific. He asked how to run a script as a non-root user. I answered. I provided an example. Sheesh.

Comment: I don't mean to be a pill, but I jump on examples that casually use `nobody` because misusing `nobody` opens security holes.